# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop console warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**code is here**

```
   <React.Fragment>
    <div className="js-container">
      <div className="js-sidecontent">
        {[{ title: "Js, values: ["s1", "s2"]}].map((f_list) => (
          <div className="js-sidecontent-container" key={f_list.title}>
            <button className="feature-title">{f_list.title}</button>
            {f_list.values.map((f_list_value) => (
              <button className="feature-title-list">{f_list_value}</button>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
```

I have the above code within the render method of React Component and I have the key-value as the property of parent div element. still, I am getting below Error in Console.

**Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

How it can be solved?

Comment: You nave a nested map. It will need a `key` at the top node too.

Comment: `{ title: "Js, values: ["s1", "s2"]}` seems to be missing a " somewhere.

Comment: Please, do some research before asking. A simple search on the warning text would have found many questions about this warning.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a `key` for the button too:

```
{f_list.values.map((f_list_value, idx) => (
    <button className="feature-title-list" key={idx}>{f_list_value}</button>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix with code like this:

```
{f_list.values.map((f_list_value, index) => (
   <button className="feature-title-list" key={index}>{f_list_value}</button>
))}
```

If you render a list of element you have to add an extra attribute key. This attribute identifies uniquely your elements.